Is there any connection between the approximate identity of the fixed point algebra and that of underlying algebra?
Let $\alpha : G\to \text{Aut}\left(A\right)$ be a finite group action on a (simple) $C^{*}$-algebra $A$. Put
\begin{equation}
A_{\alpha}=\{a\in A: \alpha_g\left(a\right)=a \text{ for all $g\in G$}\}.
\end{equation}
Suppose $\{e_\lambda\}$ is an approximate identity for $A_\alpha$. Is $\{e_\lambda\}$ also an approximate identity for $A$? Under what conditions does this question have a positive answer? Is the condition of finiteness necessary?

You used the wrong carat symbol for superscript. I fixed it for you.

@CameronWilliams Thank you for your edition.

I feel like you at least need density (or something similar?). If the subspace $A_{\alpha}$ is not dense and has a complement, then there's no telling what the approximate identity does on the complement. You should however be able to extend the approximate identity to the whole space (maybe with Hahn-Banach?).

$\{e_\lambda\}$ is an approximate identity for $A$. Indeed, we note that the following is a conditional expectation from $A$ to $A_\alpha$,
$$E: A \to A_\alpha, E(x) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g(x)$$
We note that $|G| \cdot E(x) \geq x$ for all positive $x \in A$, i.e., $E$ is of finite index. Therefore, for any $x \in A$, we have,
$$\begin{split}
\|x - e_\lambda x\|^2 &= \|(1 - e_\lambda)xx^\ast(1 - e_\lambda)\|\\
&\leq |G| \cdot\|E((1 - e_\lambda)xx^\ast(1 - e_\lambda))\|\\
&= |G| \cdot \|(1 - e_\lambda)E(xx^\ast)(1 - e_\lambda)\|\\
&= |G| \cdot \|E(xx^\ast)^{1/2} - e_\lambda E(xx^\ast)^{1/2}\|^2\\
&\to 0
\end{split}$$
where on the third line we have used $e_\lambda \in A_\alpha$ and that any conditional expectation onto a subalgebra must be bimodular w.r.t. the said subalgebra; and the final limit follows from $E(xx^\ast)^{1/2} \in A_\alpha$ and $\{e_\lambda\}$ being an approximate identity for $A_\alpha$.
Remark 1: We note that $A$ being simple is never needed. As long as $B \subset A$ is an inclusion of $C^\ast$-algebras that admits a finite index conditional expectation, then any approximate identity for $B$ is automatically an approximate identity for $A$.
Remark 2: $G$ being finite is necessary. Indeed, let $A = K(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}))$, $G = \mathbb{Z}$, and $\alpha_n(x) = s^nxs^{-n}$ where $s$ is the bilateral shift on the $\mathbb{Z}$ part of the standard basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\})$. Then $A_\alpha = \mathbb{C}p_\infty$, where $p_\infty$ is the rank one projection onto the span of the standard basis vector $e_\infty$. Then $p_\infty$ is an identity (thus also an approximate identity) for $A_\alpha$, but clearly not one for $A$.

Thank you for your excellent answer.
